# update value in list Postgres jsonb

Tags: arrays, postgresql, sql-update, jsonb

I am trying to update json

```
[{"id": "1", "name": "myconf", "icons": "small", "theme": "light", "textsize": "large"},
 {"id": 2, "name": "myconf2", "theme": "dark"}, {"name": "firstconf", "theme": "dark", "textsize": "large"},
 {"id": 3, "name": "firstconxsf", "theme": "dassrk", "textsize": "lassrge"}]
```

and this is the table containing that json column :

```
CREATE TABLE USER_CONFIGURATIONS ( ID BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY, DATA JSONB );
```

adding new field is easy I am using:

```sql
UPDATE USER_CONFIGURATIONS
SET DATA = DATA || '{"name":"firstconxsf", "theme":"dassrk", "textsize":"lassrge"}'
WHERE id = 9;
```

But how to update single with where id = 1 or 2

Comment: CREATE TABLE USER_CONFIGURATIONS (
  ID         BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  DATA       JSONB
);

Comment: i am following 
https://www.idalko.com/crud-operations-postgres-jsonb/
this is easy when you are trying to add with one key with list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Click: step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a18126aec2d2c04742fbcec6b901ef00)

```
UPDATE users                                                   -- 4
SET data = s.updated
FROM (
    SELECT
        jsonb_agg(                                             -- 3
            CASE                                               -- 2
                WHEN ((elem ->> 'id')::int IN (1,2)) THEN
                    elem || '{"name":"abc", "icon":"HUGE"}'
                ELSE elem
            END
        ) AS updated
    FROM
        users,
        jsonb_array_elements(data) elem                        -- 1
) s;
```

1. Expand array elements into one row each
2. If element has relevant id, update with `||` operator; if not, keep the original one
3. Reaggregate the array after updating the JSON data
4. Execute the `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: is that possible we can put condition in to check where id = 321 on table id

Comment: You simply can add a WHERE clause:https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9ccb3063d5663bf9482f8091d4ff35b5

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0c5f9f7c0ec50f3c1cd51902a9039df4

its adding one more value with same id  and updating existing.

Comment: Currently all expanded values of all array rows will be aggregated. For this, of course, you need a grouping: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=58e4cd95f78787dcc8e819ce4242ba4c

Comment: Did this help? Please do not forget to upvote ALL helpful answers (which honors the work and time the repliers invested into your question) and accept the best fitting answer (to close the question). Otherwise please tell us, what to change.